# Performing transformation from GHANA GRID to WGS 84 using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a shapefile which was referenced using Ghana's grid system.

I imported it to QGIS and specified WGS 84 but the coordinate bar still displays the Ghana grid values in the coordinate bar.

Is there a way to perform coordinate transformation in QGIS?

Answer (score 3):

You might have used `Set CRS for layer`. This does not reproject any coordinates.

Change it back to the original  value, and use `Save As ...` using a different file name and EPSG:4326 as CRS.

Comment: thanx ....but i have found a way to do it in arcgis

Comment: @JohnMaxwell As someone new to GIS SE, I hope you do not mind me suggesting that, since you asked how to do it in QGIS and AndreJoost has described the process for you, it seems only fair that you click the green Accept tick and upvote his answer.

Comment: sorry...did not know thats how its done here....anyway am not eligible to upvote him yet plus i tried his method in qgis and it did not work.Thank you

Comment: If it did not work for you, you might have missed the "Change it back" part.